# How to make function that swallows exceptions

Tags: kotlin

```
inline fun <T> rest(request: () -> T): T = try {
    request()
} catch (e: HttpException) {
    val requestId = e.response().raw().request().header(REQUEST_ID_HEADER) 
    if (requestId != null) {
        Dialog(requestId, R.string.oops).show(fragmentManager, null)
    } else {
        throw e
    }
}
```

It should perform some REST request (in the `request` parameter) and if it fails, and it contained the specified HTTP header, display dialog with that header.

But the compiler complains at the line with Dialog, that it doesn't return `T`, but `Unit`. But that's basicaly what I want! How can I do this?

One solution that crosses my mind it to set function's return type to `T?` and return `null`, but it feel *dirty* doing this in Kotlin.

Comment: if you don't return T in any case, why is the return type T?

Comment: You should decide to either return `null` or to throw an exception to report any problem to the caller code. Right now you try to mix both approaches

Comment: What is return value supposed to be when `Dialog.show` is invoked? If in this scenario `rest` should return nothing, its return type should be `T?` and your code should return `null` after `show` invocation. But... the client code should access returned value using [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) notation, isn't it?

Comment: You have to ask yourself what the code calling `rest()` will do in case the dialog is shown. It has to somehow deal with the absence of T (an exception or a null value), because it will *not* receive an instance of T.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning null [is not *dirty* per se](https://medium.com/@elizarov/null-is-your-friend-not-a-mistake-b63ff1751dd5). Using nulls can be abused sometimes, but this is a perfectly valid use case for using null.
Kotlin allows you to use null in safe and nice ways, so don't be afraid to use it!

Another option is to throw an exception also in the case you show the dialog (whether or not the header is present).

In order to choose, you have to ask yourself what the code calling `rest()` will do in case the dialog is shown. It *has* to deal with the absence of `T` in one way or another (null or exception). This is because showing a dialog is not something that ends the execution of your function.

Last but not least, there is also an option to deal with the result outside of the `rest()` method. Improving on Taras' answer:

```
sealed class Result<out T : Any> {
    class Success<out T : Any>(val value: T) : Result<T>()
    class ErrorWithId(val exception: Exception, val requestId: String) : Result<Nothing>()
    class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}

inline fun <T : Any> rest(request: () -> T): Result<T> = try {
    Result.Success(request())
} catch (e: HttpException) {
    val requestId = e.response().raw().request().header(REQUEST_ID_HEADER)
    if (requestId != null) {
        Result.RecoverableError(e, requestId)
    } else {
        Result.Error(e)
    }
}

private fun thingCallingRest() {
    val result = rest(::testRequest)
    when (result) {
        is Result.Success -> Log.v("__DEBUG", "success: ${result.value}")
        is Result.ErrorWithId -> Dialog(result.requestId, R.string.oops).show(fragmentManager, null)
        is Result.Error -> throw result.exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it by generic `Result` type:

```
sealed class Result<out T : Any> {
    class Success<out T : Any>(val value: T) : Result<T>()
    class Error(val exception: Exception, val requestId: String?) : Result<Nothing>()
}

inline fun <T : Any> rest(request: () -> T): Result<T> = try {
    Result.Success(request())
} catch (e: HttpException) {
    val requestId = e.response().raw().request().header(REQUEST_ID_HEADER)
    Result.Error(e, requestId)
}

private fun testRest() {
    val result = rest(::testRequest)
    when (result) {
        is Result.Success -> Log.v("__DEBUG", "success: ${result.value}")
        is Result.Error -> {
            result.requestId?.let {
                Dialog(it, R.string.oops).show(fragmentManager, null)
            } ?: run {
                throw result.exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The consumer of the result looks complicated here, why not go all the way and deal with the 3 cases separately instead? I tried to improve on your answer in mine.

Comment: Agree, it looks cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Returning null might feel ugly at first, but what are the options?

**Option 1: Throwing an exception**

If you need further information on why the code failed you should throw an exception.

Let's take a look at Kotlin's [single](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single.html) function as an example:

```
listOf<Int>().single()
```

will throw

> NoSuchElementException: List is empty.

```
listOf<Int>(1, 1).single { it == 1 }
```

will throw

> IllegalArgumentException: Collection contains more than one matching element.

This is what I mean with further information. The type of exception and the given message might provide you with ways to decide how to continue.

**Option 2: Returning null**

In case you just want to know whether it failed or not returning `null` would a good way to signal that. Even Kotlin's standard library does that for example with [`singleOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single-or-null.html).

```
listOf<Int>().singleOrNull() // returns null
```

---

Providing a fallback is also really concise using the elvis operator:

```
listOf<Int>().singleOrNull() ?: 1 // default element
```